# Twilio Call Disconnecting due to 15 seconds Silence during Processing in Flask

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-api

I'm building a Flask application that uses Twilio to handle voice interactions with users. When a user makes an order via a call, my Flask application receives the recording from Twilio and processes the order, which can take a significant amount of time.

The issue I'm facing is that Twilio disconnects the call if it does not receive a response from my application within 15 seconds. My application can't always respond within that time due to the processing required.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPK70.png)

I tried to respond immediately to Twilio with a message, and then start processing the order, but the call still gets disconnected. I understand that Twilio requires my application to return a response within 15 seconds to keep the call active.

What is the best way to handle this situation where my server needs more time to process the order? I need to ensure that the call stays active while the order is being processed and respond to the user after processing is complete.

Is there a way to keep the Twilio call active while my application is processing the order?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Can you provide a code of how to dequeue a call when a certain task is completed?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the caller on hold using the [Enqueue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue) verb and then retrieve them from hold once the processing was finished. You can customize the hold "music" to be anything you want from a ringing sound or clicking noises like someone typing - you can provide the audio that is played.

Otherwise, no, there is no way to keep Twilio from disconnecting if there is [too much of a delay](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides) waiting for your API to respond:

> Due to the real-time nature of voice calls, there is a hard upper
> timeout of 15 seconds imposed by Twilio on all call-related HTTP
> requests. This hard limit overrides any of the timers described above
> on call-processing requests, and is present to help to ensure a good
> end-user calling experience.

Here is what the Twiml will look like for an Enqueue with hold music:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
     <Enqueue waitUrl="https://yourapi.com/playholdmusic">support</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

Then the /playholdmusic could return this Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play>https://yourapi.com/holdmusic.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

After your finish processing, you will need to update the call that is holding using the [Queue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/queue) noun or the [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/redirect) verb to then continue the call.

As an aside, this will be a lot of work to gain time to process the transaction and it may be better to find a different way to handle the transaction. (Such as sending a follow-up e-mail or text message once the processing is completed).

Comment: Can you provide a code of how to dequeue a call when a certain task is completed?

Comment: If the above answer helped you, please mark it as an answer. Your application will need to keep track of when a task is complete. Then use the REST API to update the Queue Member Resource. Twilio provides code examples here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/member-resource?code-sample=code-update-the-member-resource-at-the-front-of-the-queue&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=8.x